# Cycles ignores Viewport Display as Wire setting (works fine with Eevee)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

For two cubes in my scene, I've set their *Viewport Display* to *Wire*:

[image]

The cube displays as a wireframe in the 3D viewport (with shading set to rendered) when the renderer is Eevee but if I switch the renderer to Cycles the setting is ignored:

| 3D Viewport / Eevee | 3D Viewport / Cycles |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Eevee] | [image: Cycles] |

Is this different behavior between Eevee and Cycles expected? And is there anything I can do about it?

I'm using Blender 3.3.2 LTS.

Here's the `.blend` file, if you're interested, it's just 1.8MiB:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is intentionally - you didn't say it but the viewport shading mode is _Rendered_ I guess - because in Cycles the _Rendered_ mode shows a preview of what the real raytraced rendered view would look like, whereas Eevee uses the viewport display settings. If you would hit F12 and really render the scene, both Eevee and Cycles would show the box set to Wire (if you enable them for Render, i.e. enabling the camera symbol in the outliner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles and EEVEE shares some settings, but you still have to keep in mind that they are different render engines.

Cycles doesn't use viewport display settings at all, but if you render the image (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>) it will hide objects, because they are marked as invisible in render.

As for Cycles viewport, you can uncheck Ray Visibility, since your objects are hidden in render. This will make it looks closer to EEVEE

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow. I know that I have these items disabled for render. But the image in my question are not renders. I.e. they're not the result of pressing F12, they're screenshots from the 3D Viewport. And in the 3D Viewport, I expect the _Display as Wire_ setting to be respected. It is respected even if I have the 3D Viewport shading set to rendered _if the currently selected render engine is Eevee_. Why should switching to a different render engine, i.e. cycles, affect whether this setting is ignored or not?

Comment: Or turning the question around - why does Eevee pay attention to this setting if Cycles does not? Shouldn't this kind of behavior be consistent across render engines?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can reliably answer such a question. For now, it works like this. You can ask questions about consistency at devtalk.blender.org.

Comment: Added a hint from my side.

Comment: Thanks for the _Ray Visibility_ hint - it achieves the appearance I hoped to achieve with _Display as Wire_.